# Python3, Tkinter. Не обновляется кнопка в функции

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Python3, Tkinter. Не создаётся кнопка в функции. пытаюсь заставить работать только btn[0]. функция button_clicked1 есть

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('Python Tkinter Test')
root.minsize(325,230)
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

k = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

st = int(0)

def xstroke(k, st):
    for i in range(1, 10):        
        if int(st) == int(i):
            if list1.count(str(i)) == 1:
                k[i-1] = 'X'
                list1.remove(str(i))#надо обновить кнопку как-то
                btn[i] = Button(root, bg="#DC143C", text = "\(. | .)/", command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1)
    return k, btn
def button_clicked1():
    print('1')

btn = [Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[0], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(1)), width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[1], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1),
       Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[2], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[3], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1),
       Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[4], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[5], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1),
       Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[6], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[7], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1),
       Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[8], command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1)]
for i in range(0,9):
    btn[i].pack
btn[0].place(x=35,y=35)
btn[1].place(x=105,y=35)
btn[2].place(x=175,y=35)
btn[3].place(x=35,y=90)
btn[4].place(x=105,y=90)
btn[5].place(x=175,y=90)
btn[6].place(x=35,y=145)
btn[7].place(x=105,y=145)
btn[8].place(x=175,y=145)
root.mainloop()
```

пытаюсь заставить работать только btn[0]. функция button_clicked1 есть

Comment: *пытаюсь заставить работать только btn[0]. функция button_clicked1 есть

Answer (score 2):

Просто обновите ваши функции в виджете через `config`

```
btn[i-1].config(bg="#DC143C", text = "\(. | .)/", command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всё ещё не появляется кнопка

Comment: @ВладСолодов что вам вообще конкретно надо?

Comment: чтобы btn[i] заменилось на Button(root, bg="#DC143C", text = "\(. | .)/", command = button_clicked1, width=4,height=1).pack()

Comment: @ВладСолодов зачем? просто текст и команду поменять?

Comment: @Twins, да. И цвет

Comment: @ВладСолодов зачем тогда создавать новый виджет если можно просто обновить старый. Обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ВладСолодов [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)